# indexing array in function from the pointer of some element

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

Imagine some array

```
uint8_t var[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

so `var` will be pointer to the first element of this array, and

```
uint 8_t* a=var;
b=a[3]
```

and

```
b=var[3]
```

will give the same result.

But will

```
a = &var[2];
b = a[1];
```

and

```
b=var[3];
```

be same?

Comment: Yes, pointer arithmetic is not limited to starting point at 0.

Comment: `var` is a `uint8_t[5]`. It can decay to a pointer to first element, but it doesnt always

Comment: *so var will be pointer* No. `var` is an array. It takes `5*sizeof uint8_t` bytes of memory. A pointer only takes `sizeof uint8_t *` bytes. You can use them in similar ways in most places but they are not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After this assignment

```
a = &var[2];
```

that is the same as

```
a = var + 2;
```

due to the implicit conversion of the array designator to a pointer to its first element the pointer `a` points to the element `var[2]`.

So `a[0]` yields `var[2]` and `a[1]` yields `var[3]`.

Pay attention to that the subscript operator `a[i]` is evaluated like `*( a + i )`.

So you have `a[1]` is equivalent to `*( a + 1 )` that is in turn  equivalent to `*( var + 2 + 1 )` that is to `*( var + 3 )`.

Comment: And, even, `a[-1]` yields `var[1]`.